Bootstrap hamburger menu on mobile
Hey everyone I started learning to use Bootstrap last week and so I am trying to make my beginner portfolio for practice. I'm trying to get the navbar to turn into a hamburger menu on mobile sized screens but I haven't quite figured it out. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with wrapping the entire navbar in div that has class "navbar-expand-lg" and also wrapping the list in some sort of div but I cant quite figure it out. Thanks!

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>My Portolio</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="navbar">
      <nav class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center py-3 mb-4">
        <p class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-decoration-none">
          <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
          <span class="fs-4">Name Here</span>
        </p>

        
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#about" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projects</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </section>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>

I tried wrapping the entire thing in <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg> and the list in  but it caused the list to completely disappear once it went below the large screen breakpoint

Can anyone help me with this? I think it should be pretty simple but Im stuck
